# Programa que pide 2 cadena e intercala

Tags: c

Como puedo hacer para que un programa reciba 2 cadenas desde teclado y las intercale es decir si introduzco "juan esta muy guapo" y introduzco "el sabe programar" deberá aparecer en pantalla "juan el esta sabe muy programar guapo"
Empece utilizando la funcion de string strtok para dividir la cadena pero no logro solucionarlo, aqui les dejo mi codigo:
si me pudieran corregir el código se los agradecería bastante

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

main(){
char separador[]=" ";
char cad1[100],*ap1;
char cad2[100],*ap2;    


printf("Introduce tu primer cadena\n");
fflush(stdin);
gets(cad1);

printf("Introduce tu segunda cadena\n");
fflush(stdin);
gets(cad2);

ap1=strtok(cad1,separador);
ap2=strtok(cad2,separador);

while(ap1!=NULL&&ap2!=NULL){
printf(" %s",ap1);
printf(" %s",ap2);
ap1=strtok(NULL,separador);
ap2=strtok(NULL,separador);
}


system ("pause");
}
```

Comment: ¿Y qué es lo que no funciona exactamente? Dices que falla pero no el motivo por el que falla

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo he podido resolver aquí la solución

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){

char string1[100] ;
char string2[100] ;
char seps[]   = " ";
char *token1 = NULL;
char *token2 = NULL;
char *next_token1 = NULL;
char *next_token2 = NULL;
char newString [1000];
FILE *ap;
ap= fopen("cadena", "w");
printf("introduce tu primer cadena\n");   
fflush(stdin);
gets(string1);
printf("introduce tu segunda cadena\n");
fflush(stdin);
gets(string2);
token1 = strtok_r(string1, seps, &next_token1);
token2 = strtok_r(string2, seps, &next_token2);
while ((token1 != NULL) || (token2 != NULL))
{
    if(token1 != NULL){
    fprintf (ap," %s",token1);
    token1 = strtok_r(NULL, seps,&next_token1);
}
    if(token2 != NULL){
    fprintf(ap, " %s", token2);
    token2 = strtok_r(NULL, seps,&next_token2);
}
    }
return 0;
}
```